# Invalid argument supplied for foreach in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

Below is my model, it works correctly. Right now it is returning false because there are no records for a new student. However in my controller, I have an If statement that  checks to see if the query is returned true then loops through every row in the query:

My Model:

```
function get_schedule($Student_ID)
{
    $query = $this -> db -> query("
        getstuff");

    if($query -> num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $sections= $query->result();        
        return $sections;
    }
    else     
    {           
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
$Student_ID = $session_data['Student_ID'];
$query['section']=  $this->grades_model->get_schedule($Student_ID);
$sections= array();

if ($query == TRUE)
{
    foreach($query['section'] as $row)
    {
        do stuff:
    }
}
```

The problem is it's giving me an invalid foreach loop warning because there is no data to loop through. How can I make it so it does not even attempt that loop if query is returned false. I tried adding `elseif($query == FALSE){}`, but still invalid foreach loop.

What gives, and can I just suppress that warning?

Comment: Where do you assign to `$query` in the controller?

Comment: post your complete controller code..where is `$query` coming from?

Comment: try to `print_r` the result under `<pre>` tags to see what your query returns..

Comment: print_r returns **Array ( [section] => )**

Comment: the question was not properly formatted.... he has posted the complete required code

Comment: its not `$query['section']` mate..replace it with `$query['sections']`..And also change the `if` condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not 'section'. you should keep the same name`$query['sections']`

Try this

```
 $Student_ID = $session_data['Student_ID'];
 $query['sections']=  $this->grades_model->get_schedule($Student_ID);


 if ($query['sections'] == false)
 {
  echo "error";
 }
 else
 {
  foreach($query['sections'] as $row)
  {
   do stuff:
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

TRY

**Model**

```
function get_schedule($Student_ID)
{
    $query = $this -> db -> query("
        getstuff");

    if($query -> num_rows() > 0 )
        {
         $sections= $query->result();       
         return $sections;
         }

    else     
         {          
        return false;
         }
}
```

**COntroller :**

```
$this->load->model("Model_name");
$var=$this->Model_name->get_schedule($Student_ID);
if ($var)
 {
  foreach($var as $row)
 {
  do stuff:
 }
}
```

EDIT:

Make sure to change `Model_name` to yours and query in your model

Answer (score 2):

This line `if ($query == TRUE)` isn't making much sense try checking the contents like :

```
if (isset($query['section']) && count($query['section']) > 0) {
    foreach ($query['section'] as $row) {
        // do stuff:
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
foreach($query as $row)
 {
     do stuff:
 }
```

if your $query is an array.I think the model function return an array in your case.

and also you done a mistake at

```
foreach($query['sections'] as $row)     //you did it 'section' try change it
{
    do stuff:
}
```

accept answer if it is useful

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong `$this->db->query()` is used for sql queries. You can either use `$this->db->query('select * from getstuff');` or `$this->db->get('getstuff');`

Comment: The query is correct, it's format is directly from the CI website.

Comment: @ShayanHusaini, that was an example, see at controller inside foreach loop there is dummy text `do stuff:`

Comment: May be you guyz are write... i have suggest what i found wrong.. these are the very common mistakes by programmers if you dont like my answer you may vote down my answer